# How do I log inputs and ouputs from an SSH bash session?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, read-eval-print-loop, tty

I want to build a simple test system that will allow a candidate to SSH into a bash session and which will both log all inputs provided by the candidate and be able to log and evaluate the outputs from those commands.

I want to evaluate whether a candidate will use certain commands and determine which files he has opened and what the output was. In addition I want to see a list of all commands he used and parse the outputs of those commands. I was thinking of creating aliased wrappers over VI/NANO/LESS that would log when a certain file was opened and send it to a central logging/points system.

How would I best go about this?

Comment: This probably doesn't answer you question, but some ssh clients support logging (text, screen, or raw data).  I know for a fact that PuTTY does.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bit of overkill for your requirements, but have you considered using the [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) utility?

It is specifically intended to log all input and output from a user session, although *parsing* the output file is not always trivial, especially when raw mode applications (e.g. Emacs) are involved. You can, however, replay the output file with the [`scriptreplay`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scriptreplay) program.